# how to initialize a global variable while declaring in linux environment for mips

Tags: gcc, mips

I am working in linux environment for mips processor

I am trying to declare a global variable, and that global variable is allocated in memory..
But i want to initialize that global variable while declaring itself, and i tried, that variable is being allocated,but it was not initialized with the value provided.
How can i initialize the global variable while declaring itself.
help me out.

I tried in this way..

```
    //global variable
    volatile int x =10;
    main(){
    int y;

    y =x;

    wr(0x9000_0000,x);
    wr(0x9000_0004,y);
    }
```

output:

---

```
    x variable= undefined value ('X')
    y variable = undefined value ('X')
```

when I try to write the "x" variable value into the memory location, i cannot see the value "10" .

Do I need to take an extra care while initializing the global variables while declaring itself.

IF I initialize the global variable in any one of the functions it is working properly.

```
    //global variable
    volatile int x ;
    main(){
    int y;

    x =15;
    y=x;
    wr(0x9000_0000,x);
    wr(0x9000_0000,y);
    }
```

output:

---

```
    x variable =15;
    y variable =15;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code you have shown does not produce any output. The issue is likely in the `wr()` function or in something else it calls. Note also that in your first example, you are calling `wr()` with two separate first arguments, while in the second example, the first argument is the same on both calls. Without knowing anything more about `wr()`, any "answers" would be vague hand waving and wild conjecture.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this program on a MIPS box:

```
#include <stdio.h>
volatile int x = 10;
int main (int argc , char * argv []) {
    int y = x + 1;
    printf ("%d %d\n", x, y);
    return 0;
}
```

As expected, it prints `10 11`.

Your problem must lie elsewhere.